# how to validate answers for quiz app, values which is fetched from json in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a ReactJs quiz app in which I am having problem with  validating the answers that is in the json.

I did this quiz app using react version 16.8 using state components and fetched the json data and stored in state using map function I have the completed the view part, now I started to validate the quiz and I am struggling in that part.

here is the full code:https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-firefly-2d2x5
and also ill add my json link: http://myjson.com/kpop9

I want the answer should be validated, and if user clicks the submit button before attempting all the questions it should show that you have unanswered questions and if user clicks submit after attempting all the quiz it should display the total marks that user got.

Comment: You know that you are sending the responses in the JSON and anyone doing the test could see the right responses...

Comment: I can't really write a solution for you, as it's best for you if you write it yourself - the best way to learn. The first solution that comes to my mind would be to store the current question (as you are already doing in your App component's state - which I would probably not recommend). Then, once the `submit` button is clicked, get the currently selected item from the form, iterate over your JSON of questions, find the current question by ID and compare the answers. You could also make it the way that if nothing is selected from the form - the modal/alert/toast is displayed to warn the user

Comment: Can you please explain with some code?

Answer (score 0):

Replying to your comment from above, here is your sandbox code slightly edited. You can submit an answer at any time and these are the **alerts** you should see:

- When you don't select an answer: Alert with message **No nulls**
- When answer is wrong: Alert with message **wrong**
- When answer is correct: Alert with message **correct**

[Here is your edited sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fnpt5)

The solution provided is only example, and should not be treated as a perfect solution, it's only to give you an idea of how this may work (you may still want to implement the bit, when after submitting the last answer, scores are calculated - for that you may want to store scores)

**Explanation:**

- In this example I decided to add `selected_answer` variable in the `index.js` that stores currently selected answer on the form.
- Next, I created `setAnswer` function in `index.js` which accepts a selected answer as parameter and sets the `selected_answer` in state to whatever is passed in. You are welcome to implement as many checks for the value that is passed in as you want
- `setAnswer` function is then passed to your `Answer` component, so when the value is changed, it can be saved inside `index.js` state
- `Result` component receives the `index.js` state as a `prop`. This allows it to have access to current question, the array of all questions and currently selected value
- Inside `Result` component there is a `validateAnswer` function that is triggered when `submit` button is clicked. Inside that function I use the `props.current_question` (which is the index of a question) to extract the whole question object from your JSON file. Next I filter over the array of answers from previously created `question` object, and I extract the one that has `is_right` set to 1. Finally, I check if the `props.selected_answer` is empty, and display a message if so. If it isn't, I check if it equals to the value of previously extracted correct answer object. And voila!

As mentioned before, this is not **the best** solution, but one that works on top of your code without changing much. Please let me know if you have any further questions, but hope that helps a bit.

Comment: thanks bro its working, but i need the total marks scored by the user. And the submit button should work once the user attempts all the question, suppose if he clicks the submit before attempting all the questions it should say you have unanswered questions like that.

Comment: In that case you can keep a track of all selected answers (possibly in the array?), and when the `submit` button is clicked check if the length of the array equals to the length of the questions array. If it's the same, iterate over questions, check the answers, keep the score and display. If it's not the same, show the warning/alert (you can also show which questions are not answered)